# Erro ao buscar Informações no SharedPreferences Android

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, gson

Tenho um aplicação android, e nela guardo algumas informações básicas do usuário no SharedPreferences, porém começou a apresentar o seguinte erro de parse JSON:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Códigos:

Classe para Manipular SharedPreferences:

```
public static void setPreferences(Context ctx, String key, Object value) {

    pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(arquivo, 0);
    editor = pref.edit();

    key = key.toLowerCase();

    if (key == null || value == null) {
        return;
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(value);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getPreferences(Context ctx, String key) {
    pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(arquivo, 0);
    String obj = pref.getString(key, "");
    return obj;
}
```

Código para Salvar Algo:

Obs: Converto tudo em Objeto antes de salvar.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 //Recupero o Objeto para editar o que tem gravado
 String aux = SharedPreferences.getPreferences(ctx, "configuracao");
 Configuracao c = gson.fromJson(aux, Configuracao.class);

 //Salvo Novamente
 SharedPreferences.setPreferences(ctx, "configuracao", c);
```

Na primeira vez que salvo, funciona certinho, porém quando tento buscar ele do SharedPreferences Lança a exceção acima ao fazer o cast:

```
SharedPreferences.setPreferences(ctx, "configuracao", c);
```

Classe Configuração

```
public class Configuracao {

        private String ip;
        private String porta;
        private String caminhoWebService;

        public Configuracao(){
        }


        public String getIp() {
            return ip;
        }

        public void setIp(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        public String getPorta() {
            return porta;
        }

        public void setPorta(String porta) {
            this.porta = porta;
        }

        public String getCaminhoWebService() {
            return caminhoWebService;
        }

        public void setCaminhoWebService(String caminhoWebService) {
            this.caminhoWebService = caminhoWebService;
        }


}
```

Na primeira vez que gravo o objeto configuração e chamo o getPreferences em seguida, o objeto vem dessa forma: //Funciona

```
{"caminhoWebService":"http://192.168.254.8:8084/UltraMensagensREST/recursos"}
```

Se eu fizer um set novamente, substituindo o que estava gravado, e chamar um get novamente, vem isso no retorno: //Lança a exceção

```
 "{\"caminhoWebService\":\"http://192.168.254.8:8084/UltraMensagensREST/recursos\"}"
```

Nesse caso, lança a exceção acima.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: poderia mostrar a Classe Configuração?

Comment: Opa, claro, adicionei a classe configuração, como tinha muitos campos, deixei só os necessários, mas é nesse formato.

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo do **caminhoWebService** é uma url simples? tipo: **http : // www.google.com**?

Comment: Adicionei como está me retornando no debug quando acontece o erro, se me retornasse sem essas barras "\" funcionaria sem problemas, mas por que retorna assim, tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Não entendi amigo! Sem as barras funciona?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, mas quando vou tentar gravar a segunda vez, parece que desconfigura o json, e lança a exceção acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema:

Em um método do sistema, eu estava mandando salvar uma string ao invés do Objeto Configuração, por isso estava jogando aquelas barras e desconfigurando o meu código.

> Estava fazendo assim:

```
String config = "http://......";
SharedPreferences.setPreferences(ctx, "configuracao", config);
```

> Jeito certo de fazer:

```
Configuracao configuracao = new Configuracao();
SharedPreferences.setPreferences(ctx, "configuracao", configuracao);
```